# Prove the matrix to be symmetric positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Let $M$ be a $q \times p$ real matrix. I want to prove the follwoing: if $I_p - M^\mathrm{T} M$ is positive definite, then the $(p + q) \times (p + q)$ matrix
$$
S =
\begin{pmatrix}
I_p & M^\mathrm{T} \\
M & I_q \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
is symmetric positive definite.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What are any definitions of "positive definite" that you know?

Comment: yes, $x^T A x > 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Try the block diagonal form of the matrix $S$.
\begin{equation}
S =
\begin{pmatrix}
I - M^{'}M & M^{'} \\
0 & I 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
I & 0 \\
M & I 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
S =
\begin{pmatrix}
I & M^{'} \\
0 & I 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
I - M^{'}M & 0 \\
0 & I 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
I & 0 \\
M & I 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

and using the fact that if $A$ is invertible and $S$ is positive definite $A^{'}SA$ is positive definite as well.

Comment: Finally, I get something like $y_p^{\top} (I_p - M^{\top}M) y_p + (y_p^{\top} M^{\top} + y_q^{\top})(M y_p + y_q)$. However, the latter term contains two terms $y_p^{\top} M^{\top} y_q + y_q^{\top} M y_p$ which are not clear whether they are positive.

Comment: I think I work this out. I should not expand the latter term! They can be viewed as $x^T x$. Thank you

Comment: Easier way might be using the fact that if $A$ is invertible, $A'SA$ is positive definite as well.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix are positive and that a symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only all its eigenvalues positive.

Since both $M^TM$ and $I_p - M^TM$ are positive definite, this implies that the eigenvalues of $M^TM$ must satisfy $0 < \mu < 1$. Let $(x,y)^T$ be an eigenvector of $S$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then we have

$$ x + M^T y = \lambda x \implies M^T y = (\lambda - 1)x,\\
Mx + y = \lambda y \implies Mx = (\lambda - 1)y. $$

Hence,

$$ M^TM x = M^T (\lambda - 1)y = (\lambda - 1)^2 x. $$

If $x = 0$ then $\lambda = 1$. If $x \neq 0$, then $x$ is an eigenvector of $M^T M$ associated with the eigenvalue $(\lambda - 1)^2$ which implies that $0 < (\lambda - 1)^2 < 1$. Thus, $0 < \lambda < 2$. In any case, we have shown that the eigenvalues of $S$ are positive and hence $S$ is positive definite.

Comment: Positive definite means eigenvalues are *positive*, not non-negative.

Comment: Well, it depends on the context. Sometimes people use the term positive semidefinite and sometimes they use the term positive for the same thing. In any case, the solution works for both cases. I'll edit the solution to reflect your terminology.

Comment: Could you please explain why is $0 < \mu < 1$. Thx

Comment: If $v$ is an eigenvector of $M^TM$ with eigenvalue $\mu$ then $v$ is also an eigenvector of $I_p - M^TM$ with eigenvalue $(1 - \mu)$. Since both $M^TM$ and $I_p - M^TM$ are positive definite, we have $\mu > 0$ and $1 - \mu > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that a square matrix $A$ is positive definite iff $z^\mathrm{T} A z > 0$ for all $z$, along with the factorization @karakfa gave for $S$.